# How to restrict child thread or a child process to restrict from forking in C

Tags: c, pthreads, fork, parent-child

In C language,I have a child thread(using pthreads),
Is there any way to restrict this child, so that we can't call fork inside this thread?

If we write fork inside, program should not compile.

I can also have a child process instead of child thread, as long as it cannot fork further.

Basically how can I have a child process or child thread, which cannot fork a process any further.

Comment: you're the one writing the code.  why can't you just... not call `fork()` and not have it spawn other processes?

Comment: Looks like an XY problem.

Comment: Is the main problem you are trying to solve that you want to avoid accidentally writing a fork bomb?

Comment: yeah... I was trying to avoid fork bombing problem. To avoid this problem I have written a wrapper over fork, which if called will return -1. Hence it cannot fork now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always try to play games with `pthread_atfork`: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_atfork.html

Basically, you can use `pthread_atfork()` to install a "child" callback which always calls `exit()`. This way, your threads may still fork, but the forked process will exit immediately, so no harm will be done (and only a minimal overhead incurred).

With processes it may be somewhat more complicated. Linux allows you to limit a number of processes per user (so called RLIMIT_NPROC when set with `setrlimit()`). When this limit is reached, no further forks are possible for a given user id. Thus, you can create a parent process with a `CAP_SETUID` capability and a dummy user, having the `RLIMIT_NPROC` set to 1. This way, you can fork from parent, change the child uid to that of the "limited" user you've created in advance and drop the `CAP_SETUID` capability. At this point, child will have no possible way to fork itself.